# JAVA fetch data from database table with hibernate, insert this data into new table and add extra column that came in as json data with post request

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

So the title says what i want to do, i'm making a webapp to register customerfeedback. now what i want to do is, when a post request is invoked, i wanna fetch data from a table. then i wanna store this data into a new table with an extra column. there are several criteria that needs to be given feedback to so when the post request is invoked i need to fetch one criteria and add a selected answer to this and store it in a new table. the tables allready exist.

this is an example of how the data inside the allready existing tables look:

```
{
"id": "1",
"comment": "no comment",
"ratingGroups":[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "ratingtype":"COMPANY",
        "topic": "General",
        "ratings":[
          {
             "criteria":{
                "id":"1",
                "name":"Contract",
                "description":""
             },
             "scale":{
                "id":"1",
                "fields":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "label":"Bad"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"5",
                        "label":"Good"
                    }
                ]
             }
          },
          {
             "criteria":{
                "id":"2",
                "name":"Timesheets",
                "description":""
             },
             "scale":{
                "id":"1",
                "fields":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "label":"Bad"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "label":""
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"5",
                        "label":"Good"
                    }
                ]
             }
          }]
    }]
}
```

now i want to add a selected field in every ratings array like so(this will be in my post request):

```
{
   "id" : "1",
   "comment" : "tis gelukt!",
   "ratinggroup": [{
      "id": "1",
      "ratings":[{
        "SelectedField":{
           "id":"1"
         }
       }]

}]
}
```

here is the service where i retrieve the post request

```
    package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.msf4j;

    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.dal.DalContributionRepo;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Contribution;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.ContributionTemplate;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Criteria;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Field;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Scale;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating.BaseRating;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating.BaseRatingGroup;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating.RatingType;

    import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
    import io.swagger.annotations.Info;
    import io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition;

    import java.util.HashSet;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Api
    @SwaggerDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Customer-satisfaction", version = "v1.3"))
    @Path("/customersatisfaction")
    @Service
    public class SatisfactionService {

      @Autowired
      private DalContributionRepo contributionRepository;

      @GET
      @Path("/{id}")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Contribution get(@PathParam("id") long id) {

        Contribution contribution = contributionRepository.findOne(id);
        return contribution;

      }

      @POST
      @Path("/")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public void post(Contribution contribution) {
        //here i want to fetch data from a table and store it into another table with the selected field that has come through with the post request
        //contributionRepository.save(contribution);

      }

    }
```

if it would only be one row in a table it probably won't be so hard but i have over 40 criteria's that should be answered, so over 40 "ratings". this makes that i will get a big json object with big arrays.

if you need more files tell me and i'l post them

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell which framework are you using for persistence. From your code, I assume that it is `Spring Data JPA`.

I cannot give you the code in a state where you can exactly copy paste.. But i can give you the steps that you can do to achieve what you want.

1. To retrieve baseRating

`BaseRating br = baseRatingRepo.findOne(ratingId);`

2. To convert this to Normal Rating

   `NormalRating nr = new NormalRating();
     nr.setProperty(br.getProperty());
     nr.setSelectedField(valueOfSelectedFieldbasedOnCondition);`
3. To save the normal Rating

   `normalRatingRepo.save(nr);`

From your question it's really not clear what your ask is. Hope this answer helps you in someway.

Comment: it's indeed spring data JPA. thank you for the clear answer! this might help me alot, and sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: i still have a few questions, i have to save it as a contribution, a contribution consists of an array of ratinggroups and a ratinggroup consists of an array of ratings. so instead of saving eacht rating i need to some how put all the ratings in their ratinggroup then put all the ratinggroups in a contribution and then save that contribution

Comment: uhmmmmm! I need class definition of rating, rating group, contribution to answer this question but i would recommend not to proceed this way! what you need to do is to find a tutorial online for  `JPA OneToMany` with Spring Data JPA and use it for your requirement.

Comment: i posted the classes in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Contribution.java

```
    package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models;

    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating.RatingGroup;

    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

    @Entity
    public class Contribution extends AbstractContribution<RatingGroup> {

      @OneToOne
      private ContributionTemplate template;

      @ManyToOne
      private Client client;

      @Column
      private Date date;

      @Column
      private String comment;

      public ContributionTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
      }

      public void setTemplate(ContributionTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
      }

      public Client getClient() {
        return client;
      }

      public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
      }

      public Date getDate() {
        return date;
      }

      public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
      }

      public String getComment() {
        return comment;
      }

      public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
      }

    }
```

RatingGroup.java

```
package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class RatingGroup extends AbstractRatingGroup<Rating> {
}
```

AbstractRatingGroup.java

```
    package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating;

    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.EnumType;
    import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

    //Superclass is not an @Entity, will NOT have its own table
    @MappedSuperclass
    public
    abstract class AbstractRatingGroup<T extends BaseRating> {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
      private long id;

      @Column
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      private RatingType type;

      @Column
      private String topic;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
      private Set<T> ratings;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public Set<T> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
      }

      public void setRatings(Set<T> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
      }

      public RatingType getType() {
        return type;
      }

      public void setType(RatingType type) {
        this.type = type;
      }

      public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
      }

      public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
      }

    }
```

Rating.java

```
    package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating;

    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Field;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

    @Entity
    public class Rating extends BaseRating {

      @ManyToOne
      private Field selectedField;

      public Field getSelectedField() {
        return selectedField;
      }

      public void setSelectedField(Field selectedField) {
        this.selectedField = selectedField;
      }

    }
```

BaseRating.java

```
    package be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.rating;

    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Criteria;
    import be.i8c.customersatisfaction.models.Scale;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
    import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public class BaseRating {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
      private long id;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
      private Criteria criteria;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
      private Scale scale;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public Criteria getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
      }

      public void setCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
      }

      public Scale getScale() {
        return scale;
      }

      public void setScale(Scale scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
      }

    }
```